# Can gigabit ethernet Auto-negotiation detect Cat5 cable and downgrade the mode automatically?

Tags: networking, ethernet, gigabit-ethernet

Under a Win7 PC with gigabit NIC connected to a gigabit switch, both NIC and the switch support 1000BASE-T full duplex mode, however it is connected by a Cat5 cable.

Since both devices support 1000Base-T, will they use 1G bps or they somehow know that it is a cat5 cable and therefore they both use 100Mbps. **If yes, how the auto-negotiation knows it is a cat5?**

Finally, is the network status shown in win7 indicating the mode they are using in that PHY layer (e.g. Speed: 1Gbps or 100Mbps)?

[image]

Comment: Use Cat6 Patch Cables?

Comment: I want to know is Win7 or auto-negotiation know what type of cable I use. So the doubt is when they are cat5 connected will it be displaying 100Mbps and when cat6 connected be it 1Gbps displayed

Comment: Cable cannot negotiate. If you use cable that can't work reliably at gigabit speeds, it's possible to get poor performance and unreliable operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gigabit ethernet auto-negotiation can't detect the cable type. But as a result of low quality the finally negotiated speed may be 100mbit, even when all components are capable of 1gb.

1gb over cat5(e) is working when **all 8 wires are used** by the plugs and all of them have contact in the sockets. If one of the wires aren't connected from PC to switch it may recognize only 100mbit.

1gb needs all 8 wires, 100mb needs only 4 wires.

**Failing 1gb Negotiation**
 
For speed negotiation both sides send bit patterns. If you have a really poor quality of cables or plugs, then already this negotiation may fail, even when all 8 wires are connected. This may be caused by e.g. magnetic induction due to any kind of alternating current in the near **and**  faulty shielding.

Also electrical potential differences may cause this, when one or both sides are ungrounded and there persists a high electrical potential difference.

But mostly effects like this are caused through faulty contacts or the port speed in manageable switches is manually set to 100mbit.

Comment: The "Failing 1gb Negotiation" part is really what i wanted to know. Thanks.

Comment: Note that it is not guaranteed and you would be foolish to rely on it.

Answer (score 3):

It wouldn't need to. For regular use [cat5 and cat5e](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_5_cable) work perfectly fine for gigabit ethernet, and [cat6/cat6A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_6_cable) is only really needed for 10gbe base T ethernet. I suspect the whole premise of this question is somewhat incorrect.

I *have* seen [gig-e adaptors downthrottle to base10T ethernet speeds with non standard 2 pair cat 5 cables](https://superuser.com/a/701549/10165), but I'm pretty certain, but theoratically and empirically that cat 5 works with gigabit ethernet.

You've definately downthrottled, and are running at 100Mbps line speeds, but your problem is likely not due to using to spec cat 5 cables. I suspect the trouble would be somewhere else.