# How to fix Ethernet speed being stuck at 10 Mbit in Win10?

Tags: networking, windows-10, gigabit-ethernet, internet-speed

I have a gigabit router (TP-LINK C9) and a on board network card supporting gigabit (Intel 82567lf gigabit), yet when I plug in the network cable, all I see is 10 Mbit connection.

[image: screenshot showcasing the 10 Mbit instead of the expected 1 Gbit]

How do I set the networking speed to 100 Mbit or 1 Gbit?

Comment: Try changing the cable?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek The cable is fine.

Comment: It's very, very likely that the cable is the problem. Is it professionally made? Is it gigabit rated? Is it physically intact?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz When I use it on my Laptop running Ubuntu 16.04, it defaults to 1 Gbps. And yes, the cable is gigabit-rated. It's not the problem.

Comment: It really is almost certainly the problem. Was it professionally made? How long is it? Does it follow 568A or 568B to ensure the mapping of pins to pairs is correct? Have you tried with another cable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Right click your network icon in the taskbar and select network and sharing center
2. Select your Ethernet connection
3. Select "Properties"
4. Select "Configure"
5. Select "Advanced"
6. Find Speed and Duplex, it may be on autonegoation, force 1 Gbps Full Duplex

[image: how to force gigabit]

7. Press OK
8. If you experience cable missing or undetected network, reconnect the LAN cable, or try another port on your router

You should now have 1 Gbps.

Comment: I hope I got the English phrasing correct. Also hoping for someone to edit the screenshots into their English counterpart *hint*

Comment: @JourneymanGeek That was incredibly fast. Thank you :D

Comment: Your instructions were detailed, and I was at a windows rig.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're suggesting. Are you suggesting that he force 1Gbps full duplex on only one end of the link? If so, how will the other end know to use 1Gbps full duplex if this end isn't negotiating?!

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I am the OP. This is how I solved my own problem. As in: The connection behaves and acts like a 1 Gbps via file transfers and I can now max out my Internet connection successfully.

Comment: That's a clue to the problem, but that's not the actual problem. That strongly suggests the problem is that the other end isn't negotiating. Perhaps someone/something locked that side at 1Gbps?

Answer (score 2):

If the cable quality is not up to par, gigabit Ethernet will often fall back to 10 Mbps rather than 100 Mbps. As such, it’s worth checking that your cable is cat 5e or better, the connections are secure, and your cables aren’t damaged.

Comment: Please don't use answers as comments. Once you have enough reputation, you can add comments to questions and answers.

Comment: He does have a point though - http://superuser.com/a/701549/10165 gigabit ethernet  falls back to 10mbps in many circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the order of cable ports, I had recently switched the computer end of cable with the router end. Plugging it back in original order fixed the issue.