# I am not able to get around 1000 Mbps network speed using crossover cables

Tags: networking, network-adapter, crossover-cable

I used cat 6 and cat 5e crossover cables directly between a laptop and a desktop. I set my computer ports (both of them) to max speed of 1gbps. I tried different cables. The speed does not go above 50-60 mbps. I can transfer files manually using SSD with speed of 700mbps but with these cables is limited to less than 60mbps.

Could you please help? I am skeptical of missing possible software or hardware points.

Comment: "*The speed does not go above 50-60 mbps*" -- How are you "measuring" this "speed"?

Comment: How do you use an SSD to “manually” transfer the files? What are you transferring between?

Comment: FWIW, there is no reason to use an Ethernet cross-over cable on modern systems. That is strictly for systems that need a cross-over cable which are typically legacy systems with legacy Ethernet hardware. Try using a regular Ethernet cable and see what happens.

Comment: I was gonna say that. All gig and better Ethernet does auto mdix

Comment: You probably have a miswired or poorly terminated crossover cable. Even if you used a pinout tester, you might still have a split pair. Simple pinout testers can't detect split pairs.

Comment: so 50-60 mbps (megaBits/sec) is 6.25-7.5MB/s (megaBytes/sec). is that what windows is reporting? 700mbps is 87.5MB/s, which is pretty slow for an SSD. are you sure you are using mbps when you mean MegaBits and MBps when you mean MegaBytes? are all your measurements using the same unit of measurement? I agree with the others about ditching the cross-over cable, and just using a good certified cat6 straight-through cable. also set your ports to autonegotiate. its possible to cause issues by specifying a speed and duplex when you have different device manufacturers involved.

Comment: I wonder if it's the same issue as https://superuser.com/q/701273/10165 - it's not happy with the x over and dropping down to fast Ethernet (as it's supposed to)

Comment: I'd also add to the mix - generally setting link speeds etc. is unnecessary. Autonegotiation has been around for a long time. The interfaces will negotiate the appropriate possible speed/duplex settings for the link; the highest available if nothing's wrong.

Comment: When you set the link speed, the port defaults to half-duplex. You therefore also have to set it to full-duplex.